# Android studio error after update to 3.6.2

Tags: android-studio

I recently updated my android studio from 3.5 to 3.6.2. After that for all my projects I receive below error even for new projects with clean and empty activity.

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
>
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
  >   Could not find collection.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0).
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/collection/collection/1.0.0/collection-1.0.0.jar
  >
  > Could not find lifecycle-common.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0).
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/lifecycle/lifecycle-common/2.0.0/lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar
  >
  > Could not find core-common.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0).
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/arch/core/core-common/2.0.0/core-common-2.0.0.jar
  >
  > Could not find annotation.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0).
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/annotation/annotation/1.0.0/annotation-1.0.0.jar
  >
  > Could not find constraintlayout-solver.jar (androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-solver:1.1.3).
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/constraintlayout/constraintlayout-solver/1.1.3/constraintlayout-solver-1.1.3.jar
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date

Comment: 1. did you add `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` in the app build.gradle file. 2. check whether your firewall is blocking the traffic. or try using another network. 3. did you update the gradle plugin to latest? https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Comment: Thanks @josepraveen. I changed Gradle Version from 5.6.4 to 6.0 in project structure and the problem solved. would you please tell me why version 5.6.4 wasn't working?